# navigating through pagination with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm scraping this website using Python and Selenium. I have the code working but it currently only scrapes the first page, I would like to iterate through all the pages and scrape them all but they handle pagination in a weird way how would I go through the pages and scrape them one by one?

Pagination HTML:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <a href="/PlanningGIS/LLPG/WeeklyList/41826123,1" title="Go to first page">First</a>
    <a href="/PlanningGIS/LLPG/WeeklyList/41826123,1" title="Go to previous page">Prev</a>
    <a href="/PlanningGIS/LLPG/WeeklyList/41826123,1" title="Go to page 1">1</a>
    <span class="current">2</span>
    <a href="/PlanningGIS/LLPG/WeeklyList/41826123,3" title="Go to page 3">3</a>
    <a href="/PlanningGIS/LLPG/WeeklyList/41826123,4" title="Go to page 4">4</a>
    <a href="/PlanningGIS/LLPG/WeeklyList/41826123,3" title="Go to next page">Next</a>
    <a href="/PlanningGIS/LLPG/WeeklyList/41826123,4" title="Go to last page">Last</a>
</div>
```

Scraper:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, 
executable_path=r'/Users/weaabduljamac/Downloads/chromedriver')

url = 'https://services.wiltshire.gov.uk/PlanningGIS/LLPG/WeeklyList'
driver.get(url)

def getData():
  data = []
  rows = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form1"]/table/tbody').find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
 for row in rows:
    app_number = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[1].text
    address =  row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[2].text
    proposals =  row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[3].text
    status =  row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[4].text
    data.append({"CaseRef": app_number, "address": address, "proposals": proposals, "status": status})
print(data)
return data


def main():
 all_data = []
 select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='formitem' and @id='selWeek']"))
 list_options = select.options

 for item in range(len(list_options)):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='formitem' and @id='selWeek']"))
    select.select_by_index(str(item))
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.formbutton#csbtnSearch").click()
    all_data.extend( getData() )
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form1"]/div[3]/a[4]').click()
    driver.get(url)

 with open( 'wiltshire.json', 'w+' ) as f:
    json.dump( all_data, f )
 driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried scroll down using javascript?

Comment: Where is the code block to handle _pagination_?

Comment: @DebanjanB thats what I need help with because the first three anchor tags are always the page your on I don't how to iterate through it since every page has different pages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before moving on to automating any scenario, always write down the manual steps you would perform to execute the scenario. Manual steps for what you want to (which I understand from the question) is -

1) Go to site - https://services.wiltshire.gov.uk/PlanningGIS/LLPG/WeeklyList

2) Select first week option

3) Click search

4) Get the data from **every** page

5) Load the url again

6) Select second week option

7) Click search

8) Get the data from **every** page

.. and so on.

You are having a loop to select different weeks but inside each loop iteration for the week option, you also need to include a loop to iterate over all the pages. Since you are not doing that, your code is returning only the data from the first page.

Another problem is with how you are locaing the 'Next' button -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form1"]/div[3]/a[4]').click()
```

You are selecting the 4th `<a>` element which is ofcourse not robust because in different pages, the Next button's index will be different. Instead, use this better locator -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]").click()
```

**Logic for creating loop which will iterate through pages -**

First you will need the number of pages. I did that by locating the `<a>` *immediately before* the "Next" button. As per the screenshot below, it is clear that the text of this element will be equal to the number of pages -

[image: screenshot] -

I did that using following code -

```
number_of_pages = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]/preceding-sibling::a[1]").text)
```

Now once you have number of pages as `number_of_pages`, you only need to click "Next" button `number_of_pages - 1` times!

**Final code for your `main` function-**

```
def main():
 all_data = []
 select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='formitem' and @id='selWeek']"))
 list_options = select.options

 for item in range(len(list_options)):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='formitem' and @id='selWeek']"))
    select.select_by_index(str(item))
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.formbutton#csbtnSearch").click()
    number_of_pages = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]/preceding-sibling::a[1]").text)
    for j in range(number_of_pages - 1):
      all_data.extend(getData())
      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]").click()
      time.sleep(1)
    driver.get(url)

 with open( 'wiltshire.json', 'w+' ) as f:
    json.dump( all_data, f )
 driver.quit()
```

Comment: thank you so much this worked and made perfect sense

Comment: quick question whats this doing 'preceding-sibling::a[1]' is it getting the number 13

Comment: @AbdulJamac  yes, I have also mentioned that in the updated answer.

Comment: so now whats you have the 13 does it click the next button 13 times and everytime it clicks the button it -1 from the number_of_pages

Comment: @AbdulJamac Suppose if there are 13 pages, the inner loop will be executed 12 times. Since the first page is already loaded, we only have to click the Next button 12 (13 -1) times.

Comment: hey Ive got another navigation question if you can help it would be great https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987761/navigation-using-selenium-in-python

Comment: @AbdulJamac hey, it seems that you already accepted an answer to this question. Nevertheless I gave an another solution which you can try:

Comment: what if the pagination is implemented as "Previous" and "Next", to move around you have to click the two links?

Answer (score 3):

Following approach is simply worked for me.

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("3").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("4").click()
....
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click()
```

Comment: There is no such method in WebDriver...

Answer (score 2):

first get the total pages in the pagination, using

```
ins.get('https://services.wiltshire.gov.uk/PlanningGIS/LLPG/WeeklyList/10702380,1')
ins.find_element_by_class_name("pagination")
source = BeautifulSoup(ins.page_source)
div = source.find_all('div', {'class':'pagination'})
all_as = div[0].find_all('a')
total = 0

for i in range(len(all_as)):
    if 'Next' in all_as[i].text:
        total = all_as[i-1].text
        break
```

Now just loop through the range

```
for i in range(total):
 ins.get('https://services.wiltshire.gov.uk/PlanningGIS/LLPG/WeeklyList/10702380,{}'.format(count))
```

keep incrementing the count and get the source code for the page and then get the data for it.
Note: Don't forget the sleep when clicking on going form one page to another